# Joining and grouping queries by priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 queries returning data in the same format (year - data - source)
I need to join them taking data from q1 and if the year is not present in q1 take it from q2.

Example:

Q1 result set:

```
    Year - Data - Source
    2014 - 325 - DS1
    2015 - 500 - DS1
    2016 - 450 - DS2
```

Q2 result set:

```
    Year - Data - Source
    2016 - 375 - DS4
    2017 - 475 - DS4
```

Expected result-set:

```
    Year - Data - Source
    2014 - 325 - DS1 --from q1
    2015 - 500 - DS1 --from q1
    2016 - 450 - DS2 --from q1
    2017 - 475 - DS4 --from q2
```

Comment: You should use union ... to put them in single data set, after that you can go with row_number function partition by year, Source and select where row_number = 1 ... it will give you what you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way uses `union all` and some logic:

```
select q1.year, q1.data, q1.source
from q1
union all
select q2.year, q2.data, q2.source
from q2
where not exists (select 1 from q1 where q1.year = q2.year);
```

If the subqueries are expensive, you might not want to reference `q1` twice.  One method uses `full join`:

```
select coalesce(q1.year, q2.year) as year,
       coalesce(q1.data, q2,data) as data,
       coalesce(q1.source, q2.source) as source
from q1 full outer join
     q2
     on q1.year = q2.year;
```

Comment: Went with full join. Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will also work for you,

```
Select * from Q1
Union (Select * from Q2 Where Year Not In (Select Year from Q1));
```